# Check if Enhanced Ecommerce is enabled in Google Analytics using the Management API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'd like to build a Google Sheets add-on that checks all of the views in my account to see if Enhanced Ecommerce is enabled.

Is this possible with the Management API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E-Commerce settings are configured per view,so you'd look the [view section of the management API documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles#resource). If you look into the resource representation for a view you see

```
"eCommerceTracking": boolean,
"enhancedECommerceTracking": boolean,
```

which give the status of standard and enhanced e-commerce tracking.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Rather than using Google Sheets I ended up using the `googleAnalyticsR` R library.